# overlay when i open slide-out menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an expanding navbar, I have been having difficulties implementing an overlay whenever the expanding navigation is open just like the way youtube's overlay appears when the slide out nav is open. please help.
the code has been well commented.

This is the javascript code for the expanding navigation below, i used jquery

```js
'use strict';

 // Open offsite navigation.
 $('#nav-expander').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').toggleClass('nav-expanded');
});

// Close offsite navigation.
 $('.menu .close').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').toggleClass('nav-expanded');
});

// Close offsite navigation after user click on an link in navigation.
$('.menu  a').on('click', function(e) {
    //se.preventDefault();
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-expanded');
});

$('.body').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-expanded');
});

$('.body2').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-expanded');
});

$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-expanded');
});

//ending of offsite navigation
```

```css
/************************************
*************************************
*************************************
GENERAL STYLING
*************************************
*************************************
************************************/

body{
  background-color: #F2F3F4;
}

/************************************
GENERAL STYLING ENDING
************************************/

/************************************
*************************************
*************************************
HEADER STYLING
*************************************
*************************************
************************************/

header{
  height: 57px;
  border-bottom: 1px #DDDDDD solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.main__header{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header__content__left{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__content__right{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__content__right a{
  font-weight: 600;
}

.header__margin__right{
  margin-right: .5rem;
}

.header__margin__left{
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

/************************************
*************************************
*************************************
SLIDE-OUT NAVIGATION STYLING
*************************************
*************************************
************************************/

.menu{
  position: relative;
 width: 280px;
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left:-300px; /*was originally t right when the nav bar was on the right side*/
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 text-align: center;
 transition: left 0.1s; /** default on the right **/
  overflow-y: auto; /* makes the expanding nav scrollable */
}

.menu.nav-expanded{
 left: 0; /* was at right before, for nav bar to expand from left */
}

.menu .close{
 font-size: 30px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top:10px;
}

.navbar__header{
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.nav__items__extra{
  padding: 7px 30px 7px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.menu .nav__items{
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.nav__items li{
  height: 44px;
}

.menu h4 a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav__items a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/************************************
COLORING IN THE NAVBAR
************************************/

.navbar__default {
 background: #f4f4f4;
}

.navbar__white {
 background: #fff;
}

.navbar__black {
 background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar__header__green{
  color: #28B463;
}

.navbar__header__green:hover{
  color: #28B463;
}


this is the html code for the expanding navbar.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>bootstrap homepage</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans|Droid+Serif|Noto+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ebcec35828.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>

<body class="">

<!--- This is for the header content -
------------------------------------->
  <header class="container-fluid main__header color__white">

    <div class="header__content__left">
      <a href="#" class="menu-toggle" id="nav-expander"><i class="fa fa-bars header__margin__right" style="font-size:20px;"></i></a>
      <div class="color__logo__default">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#" class="desktop__responsive__logo"><h4>spaces</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="header__content__right">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-search"></a>
      <a href="#" class="header__margin__left">Log In</a><i class="pl-1"></i>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-post-green text-white header__margin__left">Post</a>
    </div>

  </header>
<!--- Ending of the header content -
----------------------------------->

<!--- Slide-out navigation - - - - -
----------------------------------->
  <nav class="menu navbar__white">
  <a href="#" class="close"> <i class="fa fa-close pt-1 pl-2 pr-2 pb-2"></i></a>
    <h4><a href="" class="navbar__header navbar__header__green">spaces</a></h4><hr style="margin-top:0px;">
  <ul class="nav__items">
   <li class="nav__li__style"><a href="#" class="nav__items__extra"> Explore</a></li>

      

      <hr>
   <li class="nav__li__style"><a href="#" class="nav__items__extra">About</a></li>
   <li class="nav__li__style"><a href="#" class="nav__items__extra">Guidelines</a></li>
   <li class="nav__li__style"><a href="#" class="nav__items__extra">Help and Support</a></li>
   <li class="nav__li__style"><a href="#" class="nav__items__extra">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
<!--- Ending of navigation - - - - -
----------------------------------->


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you use  flex and elements side by side, menu could push content : example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXGPNZ

Comment: I know, I am trying to get a dark overlay just like youtube's overlay when the expanding navigation is open

Comment: @G-Cyr the link you shared was really good, but the dark overlay world be really helpful because I might have issues with the mobile view if I use that method.

Comment: I actually misunderstood the question ... never saw that black overlay on youtube :)

Comment: @G-Cyr no problem, the solution you gave still was really good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

You have to add an `overlay` div, with a fixed position that will cover the whole screen, next you have to set its `z-index` to be lower than your navigation panel but higher than all the other elements in your css, in your case setting `z-index: 99` works well.

Finally, and since you are using jquery, you can `show()` and `hide()` it along with your navbar.

```js
'use strict';

 // Open offsite navigation.
 $('#nav-expander').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').toggleClass('nav-expanded');
    $('.overlay').show();
});

// Close offsite navigation.
 $('.menu .close').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').toggleClass('nav-expanded');
    $('.overlay').hide();
});

// Close offsite navigation after user click on an link in navigation.
$('.menu  a').on('click', function(e) {
    //se.preventDefault();
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-expanded');
    $('.overlay').hide();
});

$('.body').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-expanded');
    $('.overlay').hide();
});

$('.body2').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-expanded');
    $('.overlay').hide();
});

$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-expanded');
    $('.overlay').hide();
});

//ending of offsite navigation
```

```css
/************************************
*************************************
*************************************
GENERAL STYLING
*************************************
*************************************
************************************/

body{
  background-color: #F2F3F4;
}

.overlay{
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 99;
}

/************************************
GENERAL STYLING ENDING
************************************/

/************************************
*************************************
*************************************
HEADER STYLING
*************************************
*************************************
************************************/

header{
  height: 57px;
  border-bottom: 1px #DDDDDD solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

.main__header{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header__content__left{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__content__right{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__content__right a{
  font-weight: 600;
}

.header__margin__right{
  margin-right: .5rem;
}

.header__margin__left{
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

/************************************
*************************************
*************************************
SLIDE-OUT NAVIGATION STYLING
*************************************
*************************************
************************************/

.menu{
  position: relative;
 width: 280px;
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left:-300px; /*was originally t right when the nav bar was on the right side*/
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 text-align: center;
 transition: left 0.1s; /** default on the right **/
  overflow-y: auto; /* makes the expanding nav scrollable */
}

.menu.nav-expanded{
 left: 0; /* was at right before, for nav bar to expand from left */
}

.menu .close{
 font-size: 30px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top:10px;
}

.navbar__header{
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.nav__items__extra{
  padding: 7px 30px 7px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.menu .nav__items{
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.menu ul{
  list-style: none;
}

.nav__items li{
  height: 44px;
}

.menu h4 a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav__items a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/************************************
COLORING IN THE NAVBAR
************************************/

.navbar__default {
 background: #f4f4f4;
}

.navbar__white {
 background: #fff;
}

.navbar__black {
 background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar__header__green{
  color: #28B463;
}

.navbar__header__green:hover{
  color: #28B463;
}


this is the html code for the expanding navbar.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>bootstrap homepage</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans|Droid+Serif|Noto+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ebcec35828.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>

<body class="">
<div class="overlay">
</div>
<!--- This is for the header content -
------------------------------------->
  <header class="container-fluid main__header color__white">

    <div class="header__content__left">
      <a href="#" class="menu-toggle" id="nav-expander"><i class="fa fa-bars header__margin__right" style="font-size:20px;"></i></a>
      <div class="color__logo__default">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <a href="#" class="desktop__responsive__logo"><h4>spaces</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="header__content__right">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-search"></a>
      <a href="#" class="header__margin__left">Log In</a><i class="pl-1"></i>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-post-green text-white header__margin__left">Post</a>
    </div>

  </header>
<!--- Ending of the header content -
----------------------------------->

<!--- Slide-out navigation - - - - -
----------------------------------->
  <nav class="menu navbar__white">
  <a href="#" class="close"> <i class="fa fa-close pt-1 pl-2 pr-2 pb-2"></i></a>
    <h4><a href="" class="navbar__header navbar__header__green">spaces</a></h4><hr style="margin-top:0px;">
  <ul class="nav__items">
   <li class="nav__li__style"><a href="#" class="nav__items__extra"> Explore</a></li>

      

      <hr>
   <li class="nav__li__style"><a href="#" class="nav__items__extra">About</a></li>
   <li class="nav__li__style"><a href="#" class="nav__items__extra">Guidelines</a></li>
   <li class="nav__li__style"><a href="#" class="nav__items__extra">Help and Support</a></li>
   <li class="nav__li__style"><a href="#" class="nav__items__extra">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
<!--- Ending of navigation - - - - -
----------------------------------->


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```